# Using past simple tense after past perfect

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past

> When X happened, I had not taken my pills because **I hadn't had** them
>   with me.
>
> When X happened, I had not taken my pills because **I didn't have** them
>   with me.

Is the second sentence grammatically sound?

Comment: **Past Perfect** marks the action that happened **earlier** than another action in the past which is marked with Past Simple. In your situation, not taking pills is not the action which happened _earlier_ than something else, that's why the verb "to take" _should not be_ in Past Perfect in your situation. In fact, both of the sentences are wrong, there shouldn't be _any_ verbs in Past Perfect there.

Comment: Both sound grammatical to me. but I think two sentences would always be better here. << _The doctor began to try to determine why I felt so faint._ I had not taken my pills because I hadn't had them with me. >> // << _The doctor began to try to determine why I felt so faint._ I had not taken my pills because I didn't have them with me. >> (The second suggests – nothing stronger – that you still don't have the pills at the time of the diagnosis.)

Comment: @YellowSky: The *had not* is correct. He was presumably supposed to have taken his pills ***before*** X happened, and he didn't.

Comment: They are both grammatical. Personally, I prefer the second sentence to the first.